# Can an iPad connected via HDMI to a TV show a different view of website

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, web, hdmi

is it possible to change the view of a website when an ipad is connected to a TV. Specifically having the HDMI tv showing something different from the ipad itself

Comment: I would be happy for technical coding answers - i.e. a javascript based solution. Or perhaps there's apps out there that allow a website to be seen differently on the TV to the iPad - for instance allowing the website to be seen in 1080p on the TV, as opposed to 4:3 as is standard with the HDMI connector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a technical troubleshooting question rather than a Javascript/HTML question.

As far as I'm aware iPads can only mirror their output and there is no solution to extend the iPad output to the TV as a secondary display.

Comment: perhaps the question should have been phrased better (i'll update it). Both really. I'm coding the site (based on wordpress, but whatever) - so a javascript/html solution would be great, or otherwise...